# Compiling sketch vi command line

Tags: arduino-ide, esp8266, compile, build, command-line

Since I don't like the text editor of the Arduino IDE, I decided to write a python script that I can invoke from my text editor to compile and upload my source. I program the popular esp8266 chip. So far I found that there is a python builder [here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/tools/build.py). This did not work for me. So is there any way to compile my source (e.g. main.ino) via a terminal command?

Answer (score 1):

In the Arduino IDE  preferences, select  external editor. Then you can write/ edit your sketches with any editor you choose. When you click compile or upload on the IDE toolbar, it will load your changes each time you compile.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [makefile](https://github.com/plerup/makeEspArduino) created to compile ESP8266 sketches. You can use this makefile from command line:

```
cd /path/to/sketch
make -f /path/to/makefile/makeEspArduino.mk upload
```