# Upload already compiled code on Linux CLI without arduino-cli

Tags: arduino-nano, uploading, linux

I have a sketch for an Arduino Nano. I'm compiling it on my build server and get these 3 files:

- `project.bin.elf`
- `project.bin.hex`
- `project.bin.with_bootloader.hex`

Now I need to be able to upload/flash them onto the board (connected via a serial interface) without `arduino-cli`. Mainly because I can't install it via `apt-get` which means I'd have to start jumping through loops to be able to use it (stuff like keeping it up to date, installing, etc. on hundreds of devices).
So I was wondering if there are any tools in the debian repositories I can use to upload the compiled sketch and if so how.

I've been looking for a solution and came across several answers and topic but strangely enough all either use `arduino-cli`, other specialized tools or link to dead pages or pages that no longer contain the answer.

Examples:

- [How to compile, upload and monitor via the Linux command line?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/15893/62872)
- [Compiling sketch vi command line](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/31160/62872)

Comment: `avrdude` is your friend.

Comment: upload Blink to Nano from IDE and then copy the avrdude command from IDE console and modify it to upload the project.bin.hex file

Comment: @Juraj do I see this command on the Windows version too? Alternatively could I get ``arduino-cli`` to output the command? Because I have test boards available I can install anything on. (I just can't get it on every board)

Comment: turn on verbose mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `avrdude`.

The command format is simple, assuming you have installed it from the Linux repositories:

```
avrdude -carduino -patmega328p -P/dev/ttyUSB0 -b115200 -Uflash:w:/path/to/project.bin.hex:i
```

Depending on what bootloader is installed in your nano you may need to change the  baud rate (`-b115200`) to 57600. Also, of course, the USB device should be set to what your board actually identifies as.

The breakdown of the command is:

```
-c<programmer type>
-p<part name>
-P<port>
-b<baud rate>
-U<instruction>
```

The programmer type, part name and baud rate can all be gleaned from the `boards.txt` file in the AVR core files.  For example, for the Nano:

```
nano.upload.protocol=arduino
nano.menu.cpu.atmega328.upload.speed=115200
nano.menu.cpu.atmega328.build.mcu=atmega328p
```

relate to -c -b and -p respectively.  The instruction will always be the same, and means "Write to flash the following file in IHEX8 format".  "flash" is the destination memory, "w" is the write command, and ":i" at the end defines the expected file format.

On a Linux computer with `avrdude` installed you can find much more information with `man avrdude`.

Comment: That answers my question, but since SE is meant as an enciclopedia of sorts, I think it would be beneficial to explain how you figure out that command line call for other boards. (And also because I managed to find a similar call after some playing around and watching the processes in ``htop`` while trying to flash with ``arduino-cli``)

Comment: @BrainStone Like that?

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much

Comment: if you are unsure of the settings that you should use, then you can use the Arduino IDE to determine them .... in settings, turn on `show verbose output during upload` .... then upload any sketch .... in the status panel in the Arduino IDE you will see the correct `avrdude` command line .... something like `E:\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CE:\arduino-nightly\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM4 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\build3bb8345d83cedc585b1cb6c2216554cb3.tmp/BasicSerial.ino.hex:i`